# Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table that contains, amongst other columns, a column of browser versions. And I simply want to know from the record-set, how many of each type of browser there are. So, I need to end up with something like this: Total Records: 10; Internet Explorer 8: 2; Chrome 25: 4; Firefox 20: 4. (All adding up to 10)

Here's my two pence:

```
$user_info = Usermeta::groupBy('browser')->get();
```

Of course that just contains the 3 browsers and not the number of each. How can I do this?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
                 ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('browser')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Superb! Just added 'browser' to the select thus: select('browser', ...) and got everything needed. You're good, you! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ravi4YtUTxo

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't it work when used with Models like User::select('country', DB::raw('count(*) as total')->otherMethods() ?

Comment: +v. use \DB instead of DB at controllers

Comment: @AmitBera can you explain the reason?, please

Comment: @JCarlos Late i know. But the \DB is needed because a controller will be namespaced in current versions of Laravel. The \DB means that your code will look for the DB class at root, rather than in the controllers namespace

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you prefer `DB::table('usermetas')->..` over `Usermeta::..` ?

Comment: Hi, @Antonio, I'm having an error on calling a member function groupBy() on array.

My laravel query is 

$patients = DB::select('select * from patients')
            ->groupBy('patients.patient_id')
            ->get(); 

How can I make this work? Thanks

Comment: I know it's an old post, however, I was wondering if someone just figure out how to get 'total records' results as mentioned in the question.

Comment: how we can sort this query by count?

Answer (score 54):

This works for me (Laravel 5.1):

```
$user_info = Usermeta::groupBy('browser')->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->get();
```

Answer (score 43):

Thanks Antonio,

I've just added the `lists` command at the end so it will only return one array with key and count:

> Laravel 4

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
    ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('browser')
    ->lists('total','browser');
```

> Laravel 5.1

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
    ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('browser')
    ->lists('total','browser')->all();
```

> Laravel 5.2+

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
    ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('browser')
    ->pluck('total','browser');
```

Comment: Thanks. One note: ->all() in the 5.1 example should be removed, since you already lists the results.

Comment: `list()` is deprecated and renamed to `pluck()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

Comment: how to sort with total after pluck and take 10 high count from this

Comment: i founded tnx 
usermetas::groupBy('browser')
            ->selectRaw('count(*) as total, browser')
            ->orderBy('total','DESC')
            ->skip(0)->take($number)->pluck('browser');

Answer (score 37):

If you want to get collection, groupBy and count:

```
$collection = ModelName::groupBy('group_id')
->selectRaw('count(*) as total, group_id')
->get();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

1. Open `config/database.php`
2. Find **`strict`** key inside **`mysql`** connection settings
3. Set the value to **`false`**

Comment: the perfect way to avoid the raw query !!

Comment: The perfect way to mess your future sql codes up! And not be able to run it on a standard database without modification.

Answer (score 10):

Works that way as well, a bit more tidy.
`getQuery()` just returns the underlying builder, which already contains the table reference.

```
$browser_total_raw = DB::raw('count(*) as total');
$user_info = Usermeta::getQuery()
    ->select('browser', $browser_total_raw)
    ->groupBy('browser')
    ->pluck('total','browser');
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel Version 8

Removed the dependency of DB

```
     $counts = Model::whereIn('agent_id', $agents)
        ->orderBy('total', 'asc')
        ->selectRaw('agent_id, count(*) as total')
        ->groupBy('agent_id')
        ->pluck('total','agent_id')->all();
```

Answer (score 4):

### Try with this

```
->groupBy('state_id','locality')
  ->havingRaw('count > 1 ')
  ->having('items.name','LIKE',"%$keyword%")
  ->orHavingRaw('brand LIKE ?',array("%$keyword%"))
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Comment: Thanks! The `havingRaw` bit is really nice since it lets you also lets you filter out the results you don't want based on the count. Comes in handy when you want to do some "and-filtering" and have joins for each filter.

Answer (score 4):

```
$post = Post::select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, category_id'))
              ->groupBy('category_id')
              ->get();
```

This is an example which results count of post by category.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is the top result when i search for `eloquent count with groupby returns only first`

using `"illuminate/database": "^9.38"` in composer. so "should" be the latest at the time of this post

I honestly have no idea why they think that returning the first record is the right option.. ie

> IMHO the current implementation doesn't make sense for queries including groupBy statements.
> Why should be N_1 be the "right" result?

> Since @taylorotwell rightly pointed out some performance issues with counting the subquery results, why don't we fix that on the php side, by checking if there are any group statements, and if so, performing a N_1 + N_2 + .... + N_M ?

https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1693#issuecomment-621167890

---

Wrapping the query and doing a count seems to work for me

```
$records = ...

$record_count = DB::table( "fake" );
$record_count->fromSub($records->select(DB::raw(1)),"query");
$record_count->count();
```

- create a "fake" query builder
- add a sub "from" from (...) query set the "sub query" to select 1 instead of returning huge column data. not sure if this is needed but in my mind it seems like a good idea
- do the normal ->count()

returns the "expected" result since it executes:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from (select 1 from ... group by ...) as `query`
```

The sub is the "query" that `$records` would normaly execute

---

My use-case is for pagination (not using laravel). so i get the record count then pass it to the paginator then call `->forPage()->get()`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/44081#issuecomment-1301816710

Comment: I've been searching for hours only to find that its a known issue. Thank you so much mate

Comment: For someone supporting a version lower than 5.8 you need do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838367/4308270) (working on my 5.5). since `fromSub`  isn't available for versions before 5.8 .

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be this:

```php
$data = Usermeta::orderBy('browser')->selectRaw('browser, count(*) as total')->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Eloquent query that uses the GROUP BY clause with advanced aggregation functions and conditional statements.

*GroupBy on one column*.

```
$data = Employee::select(
  'department', 
  DB::raw('SUM(salary) as total_salary'), 
  DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_employees'), 
  DB::raw('SUM(IF(bonus > 13000, 1, 0)) as employees_with_bonus')
)
->groupBy('department')
->havingRaw('total_employees > 5 AND total_salary > 10000')
->orHavingRaw('department_rank LIKE ?', array("%$keyword%"))
->get();
```

In the above query, if the `bonus` is greater than 13000, the `IF` function returns 1 otherwise it returns 0.

*GroupBy on two columns*: The groupBy method takes multiple arguments

```
$data = Employee::select(
  'department', 
  'location', 
  DB::raw('SUM(salary) as total_salary'), 
  DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_employees'), 
  DB::raw('SUM(IF(bonus > 1000, 1, 0)) as employees_with_bonus')
)
->groupBy('department', 'location')
->havingRaw('total_employees > 5 AND total_salary > 10000')
->get();
```

*GroupBy and JOIN*: Laravel Eloquent query that joins two tables and uses grouping and aggregate functions. (inner join)

```
$data = Employee::select(
  'employees.department', 
  'employees.location', 
  DB::raw('SUM(employees.salary) as total_salary'), 
  DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_employees'), 
  DB::raw('SUM(IF(employees.bonus > 1000, 1, 0)) as employees_with_bonus')
)
->join('departments', 'employees.department', '=', 'departments.name')
->groupBy('employees.department', 'employees.location')
->havingRaw('total_employees > 5 AND total_salary > 10000')
->get();
```

*Raw MySQL Query*:

```
SELECT 
  department, 
  SUM(salary) AS total_salary, 
  COUNT(*) AS total_employees, 
  SUM(IF(bonus > 1000, 1, 0)) AS employees_with_bonus 
FROM 
  employees 
GROUP BY 
  department 
HAVING 
  total_employees > 5 AND total_salary > 13000;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get sorted data use this also

```
$category_id = Post::orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->select(DB::raw('category_id,count(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8 you can use `countBy()` to get the total count of a group.

Check the documentation on the same.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-countBy

Comment: This is for Collections and not for Eloquent models.  It would be inefficient to get all of the records from the database and then perform a groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution(tested with Laravel 9 and Spatie/Permissions).

Controller:

```
//Get permissions group by guard name(3 in my case: web, admin and api)
$permissions = Permission::get()->groupBy('guard_name');
```

View:

```
@foreach($permissions as $guard => $perm)
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="permission">Permissions ({{ ucfirst($guard) }}) {{ count($perm) }}</label>
    <select name="permission[]" id="permission" class="form-control @error('permission') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
      @foreach($perm as $value)
        <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('permission')
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ $message }}
      </div>
    @enderror
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints all columns data. It works for me:

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas as u1')
    ->leftJoin('usermetas as u2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('u1.browser', '=', 'u2.browser')
             ->whereRaw('u1.created_at < u2.created_at');
    })
    ->where('u2.id', '=', null)
    ->select('u1.*')
    ->orderBy('u1.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

#laravel9 :

```
User::select('city','count, count(*) as total')->groupBy('city')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution...!

```html
        $listStock = DB::select("
        SELECT 
        P.id_producto
        ,P.id_modelo
              ,P.id_carroceria
        ,P.nombre
        ,P.descripcion
        ,P.url_image As url_image_principal
        
        ,PM.id
        ,PM.orden
        ,PM.url_image AS url_image_detalle
        
      FROM pre_producto P 
            LEFT JOIN pre_producto_imagenes PM ON P.id_producto= PM.id_producto WHERE  P.id_seccion = 1 ORDER BY P.id_producto asc");

              $arraysData = [];
        foreach ($listStock as $key => $value) {

            $arraysData[$value->id_producto][] =  $value ;
          
        }

        dd($arraysData);
        exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more Laravel way to handle group by without the need to use raw statements.

```
$sources = $sources->where('age','>', 31)->groupBy('age');

$output = null;
foreach($sources as $key => $source) {
    foreach($source as $item) {
        //get each item in the group
    }
    $output[$key] = $source->count();
}
```

Comment: This is memory and processing hungry.

Comment: Same memory pb for me