# laravel Eloquent ORM - How to get compiled query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, compiled-query

In [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/releases#laravel-4.2) I want to get Compiled Query.

This is what i have:

```
$product = Product::where('id', '=', '100')->get();
```

I want compiled query like:

```
select * from products where id = 100
```

Purpose of the question is: i want to use it as sub query in another query.

I have searched and found [Class Grammer](http://v3.golaravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Database.Query.Grammars.Grammar.html) and [Class MySQL](http://v3.golaravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Database.Query.Grammars.MySQL.html) But i did not found solution for that.

Is there any solution?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is how you do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/24838367/784588

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use `grammer` for `subqueries`, See below example for reference :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->where('user.id', '=', $userID)
             ->join('product', 'product.userid',  '=', 'user.id');

$price = $users->select(array(DB::raw('SUM(price)')))
               ->grammar
               ->select($users); // Compiles the statement

$result = DB::table('users')->select(array(DB::raw("({$price}) as price)))->get();
```

This add a subquery to your main query.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably mostly finding out what query was just executed, rather than what the query will be. Something like this:

```
function latestQuery()
{
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    return end($queries);
}
```

Hopefully that's the same for your purposes.

Comment: my purpose is something different. i want to use it as 'subquery' in another query.

Comment: You really have to explain better what you're after because this is the closest you're gonna get to the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the SQL query like this:

```
use DB;//write this at the top of the file above your Class 

DB::enableQueryLog();//Enable query logging
$product = Product::where('id', '=', '100')->get();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());//print the SQl query
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register an event listener in your routes file(in development phase), which will listen for the  laravel query event and `var_dump` the executed query.

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql)
{
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

But this will turn out to be messy. So better use something like [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork-chrome). It is awesome, you can view all the executed query in your browser.

Comment: my purpose is something different. i want to use it as 'subquery' in another query.

Comment: What exactly are you intending to do? Be more specific.