# How to build subqueries in Laravel-5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How can I build the following MySQL query using Laravel-5?

```
select orders.*, oi.items from orders 
inner join (select order_id, group_concat(item_name SEPARATOR ', ') as items 
from orders_items group by order_id) as oi on oi.order_id = orders.id;
```

***EDIT***

The suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder) did not resolve my problem, however I did find a solution and will post it below for others.

Answer (score 2):

```
$order  = $order->select('orders.*', 'oi.items');
$order->join(DB::raw('(select order_id, group_concat(item_name SEPARATOR ",") as items from orders_items group by order_id) as oi'), function($join)
{
    $join->on('oi.order_id', '=', 'orders.id');
});
$order->whereRaw('find_in_set ("'.$value.'", oi.items)');

$rows = $order->get();
```