# Sub Query in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have below mysql query to run in laravel but i am not able to figure out how should i implement it.

Here is MYSQL query.

```
SELECT temp.*,count(temp.respondent_id) FROM (SELECT * FROM `responses` GROUP BY respondent_id) as temp GROUP BY DAY(`temp`.`created_at`)
```

I am getting expected result with it. Please help me out.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in something like that?

Comment: No, I have read this link. But here my table coming from query which is same table.

Comment: So maybe something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder

Comment: Yes. It can be work. But i just have implemented this solution.

 "" $data = \DB::select(\DB::raw('SELECT count(temp.respondent_id) as respondent, DATE(temp.created_at) as date FROM (SELECT * FROM `responses` GROUP BY respondent_id) as temp GROUP BY DAY(`temp`.`created_at`)')); ""

AND yes it is working. :)

Comment: I am happy that I could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have got solutions.

As [stachu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936476/stachu)
given link "[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder)" in comments.

& another way is as below

```
$data = \DB::select(\DB::raw('SELECT count(temp.respondent_id) as respondent, DATE(temp.created_at) as date FROM (SELECT * FROM `responses` GROUP BY respondent_id) as temp GROUP BY DAY(`temp`.`created_at`)'));
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $result = DB::select("SELECT temp.*,count(temp.respondent_id) FROM (SELECT * FROM `responses` GROUP BY respondent_id) as temp GROUP BY DAY(`temp`.`created_at`)");
```