# Laravel 5.0 Join Sub Query With Request Paramters

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to create a very complex query, I've simplified it as much as possible (2 select statements, are concatenated to the main query), the code below, works only If there are no "date" parameters sent in the request, When parameters sent, I got an error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031"

I think the problem is in toSql() method, but I don't know what else could I use 
to solve that?

**Update:** I need to keep leftJoin method so I can't use mergeBindings method

```
    // 1st select statement
    $earnQuery = DB::Table('san_charity_point_earn')->select('charity_id','earn_date',DB::raw('count(user_id) as users,sum(points) as earn_points,count(transaction_id) as earn_trans'))
    ->where(function($q) use($request){
        // filter paramters
        if($request->has("from")){
            $q->where("earn_date",">=",$request->from);
        }

        if($request->has("to")){
           $q->where("earn_date","<=",$request->to);
        }
    })
    ->groupBy('charity_id')
    ->toSql();


    // 2nd select statement
    $redeemQuery = DB::Table('san_charity_point_redeem')->select('charity_id','redeem_date',DB::raw('sum(points) as redeem_points,count(transaction_id) as redeem_trans'))
    ->where(function($q) use($request){
        // filter paramters
        if($request->has("from")){
            $q->where("redeem_date",">=",$request->from);
        }

        if($request->has("to")){
           $q->where("redeem_date","<=",$request->to);
        }
    })
    ->groupBy('charity_id')
    ->toSql();


  //full Query  
  $charities = DB::table('san_charity')->select('san_charity.charity_id','title_ar','title_en',DB::raw('
        COALESCE(users,0) as users, 
        COALESCE((earn_trans+redeem_trans),0) as transactions, 
        COALESCE(earn_points,0) as earn_points,
        COALESCE(redeem_points,0) as redeem_points'))
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw('('.$earnQuery.') earn'),function($join){
            $join->on('earn.charity_id','=','san_charity.charity_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw('('.$redeemQuery.') redeem'),function($join){
            $join->on('redeem.charity_id','=','san_charity.charity_id');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: In dealing with subqueries and Laravel's query builder, you'll need to remember to merge bindings from the subqueries into the "master" query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder

Comment: @mopo922 thx for the lookup. I added another one

Comment: @mopo922, Thank you, but the questions you referred to didn't solve my problem .... I still need to keep left join and don't need to replace it with mergeBindings ... also getQuery() is undefined method!!!

Comment: @Drew, Thank you, but please check the update

Comment: `mergeBindings()` doesn't replace `join()`, it is used in partnership with it. I believe `getQuery()` replaces `toSql()`.

Comment: @mopo922 so If mergeBindings() doesn't replace join(), How will the query look like? How do I use them both??