# how to select from subquery using query builder in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, select

please help me,
i have query: 
SELECT * from (select * from products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) AS result ORDER BY discount DESC LIMIT 14

so, how to convert into query builder in laravel 5.
tks!

Comment: have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder), might help.

Comment: tks guy, i did it

Answer (score 2):

Using the query builder and importing (use) DB, allows you to build and fetch the result you want.

```
use DB;

$result = DB::table(
    DB::raw("(" . 
        DB::table('products')
          ->select('*')
          ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
          ->limit(20)
          ->toSql()
        . ") as result"
    )
)
->select('*')
->orderBy('discount', 'desc')
->limit(14)
->get();
```

table() selects the table you want to query. In this case we are building up a separate SQL statement to fetch the table.

select() the columns you would like to see.

orderBy($column, $direction) where $column is the name of the column you would like to order and $direction is the order, desc or asc.

limit($limit) only return $limit items to the result set.

toSql() returns the current QueryBuilder SQL statement as a string.

get() returns the data in a Collection.

Also added in the missing discount ordering.

Comment: please add some context to your answer. just code alone usually doesn't make for good answers

Comment: I think you've missed the "ORDER BY discount DESC"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

Products::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->orderBy('discount', 'desc')->take(14)->get();

Comment: tks guy, i tried it, but result not orderBy('discount'). it given 14 record orderby('id', 'desc'). Do you have any other making?

Comment: You can use:
$q = Products::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->get(); 

And after that

$test = $q->sortByDesc('nome')->take(14);

See if this works