# How Can I get Min or Max value from Union result with Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to get a min value from union table.

As a MySQL Query like below.

```
SELECT MIN(PromisedDate) 
FROM (SELECT PromisedDate FROM JobWorkOrder WHERE `PromisedDate` IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT ScheduledDate AS PromisedDate FROM JobPhase WHERE `ScheduledDate` IS NOT NULL) ScheduledTable;
```

This Query's result is min value of PromisedDate and ScheduledDate in JobWorkOrder and JobPhase Table.

So I built a Laravel query like below.

```
$JobPhase = JobPhase::where('ScheduledDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('ScheduledDate AS PromisedDate');

$minDate = JobWorkOrder::where('PromisedDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('PromisedDate')
    ->union($JobPhase)
    ->min('PromisedDate');
```

But I got a wrong result.
The result is

```
(SELECT MIN(`PromisedDate`) FROM `JobWorkOrder` WHERE `PromisedDate` IS NOT NULL) 
union 
(SELECT `ScheduledDate` AS `PromisedDate` FROM `JobPhase` WHERE `ScheduledDate` IS NOT NULL)
```

How can I build a Laravel query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get min from the get() function result.
Simply added a get() function to your query.

```
$JobPhase = JobPhase::where('ScheduledDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('ScheduledDate AS PromisedDate');

$minDate = JobWorkOrder::where('PromisedDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('PromisedDate')
    ->union($JobPhase)
    ->get()
    ->min('PromisedDate');
```

Then you will get a MIN value.

Answer (score 2):

The `min` field is selected from subquery:

```
$JobPhase = JobPhase::where('ScheduledDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('ScheduledDate AS PromisedDate');

$sub = $JobWorkOrder = JobWorkOrder::where('PromisedDate', '<>', null)
    ->select('PromisedDate')
    ->union($JobPhase);

$minDate = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
    ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
    ->min('PromisedDate');
```

See also: [How to select from subquery using Laravel Query Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder)