# Laravel 5.6: how to create a subquery using Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to reproduce following mySQL query using Laravel query builder:

```
*SELECT SUM(scores) FROM (SELECT scores FROM player_games WHERE player_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) scores
```

Any suggestions?

Here the solution:

```
    $sub = playerGame::where('player_id',1)->where('scores','>',0)->limit(2)->orderBy('id','desc');

    $count = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
   ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery()) 
   ->sum('scores');
   return $count;
```

Comment: $responce= DB::table('player_games')->sum('amount')->where('player_id ', 1)->order_by('id','desc')->limit(2)->first(); i think some thing like this.

Comment: Hi, it does not work. I also tried yesterda.

Comment: please show the error and your code.....

Comment: This is the query: $res = DB::table('player_games')->sum('scores')->where('player_id',1)->limit(3)->first();

Comment: Error: Call to a member function where() on string"

Answer (score 1):

Use `fromSub()`:

```php
$sub = playerGame::select('scores')
    ->where('player_id', 1)
    ->where('scores', '>', 0)
    ->limit(2)
    ->orderBy('id','desc');
$sum = DB::query()->fromSub($sub, 'scores')->sum('scores');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$responce= DB::table('player_games')->where('player_id',1)->sum('amount');
        dd(collect($responce)->sortByDesc('id')->take(2));
```

please cheack this one.....i try it's work....and add use DB;in the top of controller....

Comment: It returns 120...all the scores...not limit 2

Comment: Please see this if still facing any problem then ping me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the link...now it works...I posted the solution above.