# Laravel Count Records in coumn

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel eloquent how would on retrieve a count of store sales by date for example I would want

Result

```
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| Store   | 17/01  | 18/01  | 19/01 |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1       | 0      | 1      | 1     |
| 2       | 1      | 1      | 0     |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Table

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| Sale  | Store  | Date  |
+-------+--------+-------+
| 1     |  1     | 19/01 |
| 1     |  1     | 18/01 |
| 1     |  2     | 18/01 |
| 1     |  2     | 17/01 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I have tried this

```
 $contracts = \App\Sales::select('Store','Date')
            ->where('Date', '>=','1/1/2016')
            ->groupBy('Store','Date')
            ->get();
```

This returns a collection of data, I know I could loop through the data in a `foreach` but was wondering could I do it in sql easier?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group

Comment: I would check this as duplicate?