# get average for every single object seperated not all objects in one row

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table **places** and table **rating**.
Every place have multiple rows in rating table.
I want to get all places and every place object should have one property called **user_rating**. Its value is the average of **rating.rate_no** for this place.If there is no ratings for this place (no rows in rating table) user_rating should be 0
My code is:

```
$data = DB::table('places')
    ->join('rating', 'places.id', '=', 'rating.place_id', 'left outer')
    ->select(
        'places.*',
        'rating.rate_no',
        DB::raw('avg(rating.rate_no) as user_rating')
    )
    ->groupBy('rating.rate_no')
    ->get();
```

This code group all places in one object with avarage(rating) which I do not want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Comment: Just apply avg() instead of count() as shown in the duplicate topic.

Comment: @Shadow it did not work , i will put the **new code** in the next comment,help me if you can .

Comment: $data = DB::table('places')
        ->join('rating', 'places.id', '=', 'rating.place_id', 'left outer')
        ->select(
            'places.*',
            'rating.rating_no',
            DB::raw('avg(rating.rating_no) as user_rating'))
        ->groupBy('rating.rating_no')
        ->get();

Comment: The did not work is not a proper error description, pls provide details as to what exactly that means. Btw, the solution described there does work, so you probably implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: the result became 9 objects with user_rating from 2 - 10 .there is 4000 place object in database

Comment: Use leftJoin method instead of join.

Comment: I already use left outer join to get all places even if its not have ratings in raing table.

Comment: Then you would have a record for all 4k places.

Comment: no i would not. I want every single place of the 4K places in a single object with its data beside this data i want the avarage of its rating from the rating table