# Laravel Eloquent return count of each group with groupBy()

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to `groupBy()` task using Laravel Eloquent. I have searched Internet and didn't find anything with eloquent.
some people used groupBy() query with Query Builder like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

But I want to create query like this style:

```
Task::select('id')->groupBy('category_id')->count();
```

This code just return only count of first `category_id`. But I want count of all the `category_id`.

Answer (score 32):

Native Collection alternative (grouped by php, not mysql). It's a nice option when you have the Collection as variable already assigned. Of course is less optimal than mysql grouping in most cases.

```php
$tasks->groupBy('category_id')->map->count();
```

Comment: If you ask about `map` - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#higher-order-messages

Comment: This is helpful for my problem. It works by single line.

Answer (score 4):

You should add the count to the select function and use the get function to execute the query.

```
Task::select('id', \DB::raw("count(id)"))->groupBy('category_id')->get();
```

The `\DB::raw()` function makes sure the string is inserted in the query without Laravel modifying its value.

Comment: Changing **\DB::raw("count(id)")** to **\DB::raw("count(id) as total_count")** would be more useful for further operation.

Answer (score 3):

More simple:

```
Task::select('id')->groupBy('category_id')**->get()**->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

output:

```
return $email_trackers = EmailTracker::get()->groupBy('campaign_id')->map->count();
     
{
  "6": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
return DB::table('offers')->select('*', DB::raw('count('.$field.') as total_count'))->groupBy($field)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I overrode the `count()` method in my model. Could be something like:

```
public function count($string = '*'){
    $tempmodel = new YourModel();
    return $tempmodel ->where('id',$this->id)->where('category_id',$this->category_id)->count($string);
}
```

This gave me exactly the behavior of `count()` I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me as

> we need to select one column like 'category_id' or 'user_id' and then
>   count the selected column on get()

```
    Task::select('category_id')
           ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
           ->groupBy(['category_id'])
           ->get()
           ->count();
```

Comment: please consider explaining what have you changed to make it work