# Request giving count of each distinct family

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am looking for a sql request which will provide this kind of result.

```
id | family       result :
 1     A          [A => 2, B => 1, C => 1]
 2     A
 3     B
 4     C
```

Preferably using eloquent.

**Current solution :**

```
materials()->select('family', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
           ->groupBy('family')
           ->pluck('total', 'family');
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? This is not a code-on-demand site...

Comment: A simple groupBy and count query would provide you with this.

Comment: The request I try doesn't work at all, so I don't wan't to lead people in a wrong direction

Comment: Don't worry, anyone with some basic SQL knowledge won't be misled by your attempts

Comment: Sandeesh, no it doesn't provide the family name associate

Comment: I see, you get the result the way i mentioned and perform a transformation on the collection to get this result. I'll whip up a code for you if you can't get it done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Comment: I will look to the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) function that Guillaume use and come back

Comment: @Sandeesh the pluck did what I wan't, that the things I was missing. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$plop = Plop::selectRaw('family, COUNT(id) AS total')->groupBy('family')->pluck('total', 'family');
```

As you has not given enough details, it's hard to be precise.

Comment: Thanks for the pluck function, I will look in this way

Comment: @ThomasPetillot This does exactly why you need

Answer (score 0):

With laravel eloquent, using `groupBy()` and `count()`:

```
$model=Model::get()->groupBy('family');
foreach($model as $key => $mod)
 {
        echo $key;
        echo (count($mod));
 }
```