# Count by categories in Laravel eloquent relationships in model rather than query builder

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have post Model which has multiple reactions (Like, dislike etc)

I want to count those reaction by their attr_id. I tried below code and it gives total number of reactions on post.

```
public function PostReaction() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostReaction');
    }

public function getAttributesCountAttribute() {
        return $this->PostReaction()->count();
}
```

and if I do

```
return $this->PostReaction()->groupBy('attr_id')->count();
```

It returns only first reaction count instead of all.
It should give array of count with all reactions

Comment: count() doesn't return an array, so it shouldn't give an array of the counts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Comment: The query builder and ORM methods are the same...  did you even try it?

Comment: I mean to say eloquently.

Comment: Eloquently?  Eloquent is the ORM and Eloquent extends the query builder so the methods are the same.

Comment: I already have tried below code

return DB::table('post_reaction_relation')
                 ->select('attr_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total,attr_id'))
                 ->groupBy('attr_id')
                 ->get();

it will not use model relationship it will give you all results instead of count only related to this post

Comment: I figured it out. And yes I may not know everything since new to Laravel. And it would be more cool if you could have answered in a polite way. Never think you know everything

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using below code

```
return $this->PostReaction()
                 ->select('attr_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total,attr_id'))
                 ->groupBy('attr_id')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have this error because `$this->PostReaction` returns the reactions of all posts.

Try to call the function outside the model by making a repository class where you'll have the method getAttributesCountAttribute and pass to it the $post on which you want to count the reactions. Something like:

```
public function getAttributesCountAttribute($post) {
        return $post->PostReaction->count();
}
```

Same thing if there is multiple posts, try to loop for each post and get its reactions not all at once.

Comment: Why downvote? Can you explain what is not clear to help move his issue forward?

Comment: @B_Yanis I don't see how this is an answer.  How does this solve the problem at hand?  It just adds a level of abstraction but will return the same result as count() returns an integer, not an array.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `$this->PostReaction->count()`; without the () in PostReaction? It is a dynamic property provided automatically by Eloquent.

Make sure to define a relationship in the PostReaction Model too the PostReaction belongsTo one Post.

If the post has many reactions I think it should be clearer to call the method reactions and count the reactions like that : `$post->reactions->count();`
If you want to get only the 'likes' you can chain the conditions like that : `$post->reactions->where('reaction', 'like')->count();`

For more details you can check the OneToMany relashionship in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: I tried without () in count  but it throws an error.Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$count