# Fetching groups and the size of every group

Tags: laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

So, i have a mongo database filled(21k enteries) with columns like action(there are 5 different actions) id, time, etc.

I need to get the name of every action, and how many times does this action occur. For example: USERPROPERTY_CHANGED - 755

I have tried pretty much everything in here [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Then i tried to make anothe collection, where i input the fields one, by one, and then fetch them, but my migration looks like this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class actionPopularity extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('actionPopularity', function (Blueprint 
$collection) {
        $collection->Increments('id');
        $collection->string('action');
        $collection->integer('count');
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('actionPopularity');
}
}
```

But the collection that this generated had only one field - id.

heres something that kind of works (it shows that it can work with the database)

```
    Controller:

public function database_test()
{
 $actions = Action::groupBy('action')->get();

 return view('database_test',compact('actions'));
 }
```

view:

```
  {{$actions}}
```

output:

```
        [{"_id": 
{"action":"OBJECT_INSERT"},"action":"OBJECT_INSERT"}, 
        {"_id": 
{"action":"OBJECT_MODIFY"},"action":"OBJECT_MODIFY"}, 
       {"_id": 
        {"action":"null"},"action":"null"},{"_id": 

{"action":"USERPROPERTY_CHANGED"},"action":"USERPROPERTY_CHANGED"}, 
       {"_id":{"action":"OBJECT_DELETE"},"action":"OBJECT_DELETE"}]
```

ultimately i want to get two arrays, one with action names, and another one with the amount of times that this action has been called, to put it in a chart.