# How do I count the number of Items in a grouped collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Please I want to count the number of Items in each grouped collection. assuming the collection returns three group Items, I want to count the collection in each group

I did this but it isn't working out for me

```php
$collection = Vendor::all();
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('vendor_discount');
$counted = $grouped->countBy();
return $counted->all();
```

this is the error am getting back

> `array_key_exists()`: The first argument should be either a string or an integer

by doing this

```
$user_info = DB::table('vendors')
                 ->select('vendor_discount', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('vendor_discount')
                 ->get();
```

this is the results

```
0: {vendor_discount: null, total: 1}
total: 1
vendor_discount: null
1: {vendor_discount: "10%", total: 2}
total: 2
vendor_discount: "10%"
2: {vendor_discount: "20%", total: 2}
total: 2
vendor_discount: "20%"
```

how do I correctly display in a view template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group

Comment: Hey, It works but am find it difficult to display in a view template

Comment: can you show what output you are getting after the query?

Comment: ```0: {vendor_discount: null, total: 1}
total: 1
vendor_discount: null
1: {vendor_discount: "10%", total: 2}
total: 2
vendor_discount: "10%"
2: {vendor_discount: "20%", total: 2}
total: 2
vendor_discount: "20%"```

Comment: Please is it readable?

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly check for the correction representation of the collection

Comment: at the end of your query use ->get()->toArray(); which will give you your result in an array. Just read the array.

Comment: Please am seeing the same thing. Nothing has change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query

```
$user_info = DB::table('vendors')
                 ->select('vendor_discount', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('vendor_discount')
                 ->get()->toArray();

return $user_info;
```

then in the view file

```
//Loop through the values
foreach($user_info as $user){
    echo $user->vendor_discount." - ".$user->total;
}
```

Comment: It works..Was able to display in Vue template too..Thanks alot