# Laravel Eloquent Array foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

Hey guys Im new to laravel. I have this table

[image]

How will i able to fetch count of 'is_correct' column for each subject?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replace the Model with your eloquent model name

```
Model::select(
'subject_id',
 Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw("COUNT(is_correct) as count")
)
->groupBy('subject_id')
->get();
```

Comment: hey man tried this but no luck it gives me a database error 1055 thanks!

Comment: Can you share the error message? and the code you tried?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check whether it's working

Comment: Hey dude @Kenath. I think it works now and had a syntax error. This is a great help thanks a lot. Anyway I also find this very similar if someone need it. [similar_scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)