# How can i orderby and groupby in one query in laravel

Tags: eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-5.8

I'm facing a problem when trying to order after using groupBy
I wanna sort the grouped entries but its not working here is what I was trying to do

```
$errors = UserErrors::all()->groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('id');
```

Comment: 1) You havn't included an error message or anything actually demonstrating the problem.  2) If you're grouping by `user_id`, then there will be one row per `user_id` in the results, which means there wouldn't be an `id` to order by.  3) You haven't included a `select` to express how you're aggregating the rows.  ***Conclusion:*** Make your query work *without* the `orderBy`, and only *then* move on to adding the `orderBy`, perhaps starting with this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$errors = UserErrors::groupBy('feild_name')->orderBy('feild_name','DESC')->get();
```

Example as below

```
$query->where('feild_name', '=', 'active')
    ->groupBy('feild_name')
    ->orderBy('date','DESC')
    ->get();
```