# Query reports and group by user and count certain field

Tags: sql, laravel

I have this report migration

```
$table->unsignedInteger('target_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
$table->string('reason'); // can be one of three values, say ('bad, 'good', 'something')
```

i want now to display a table where i have the user and column for each reason counting how many times he got records on this

```
user | bad | good | something
Jeffrey | 3 | 10 | 2
```

how to query this one ? and have a collection where i can loop and display rows in table :)

Comment: You may find a similar solution to this thread: [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Comment: `YourModel::groupBy(user and reason)`

Comment: @DG_ Nope tried that but i don't get what i need + when i use two groups i get only first record

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yup that's what i need but what's the right syntax ? tried this 
`AccountReport::groupBy('user_id', 'reason')->get()` didn't work

Comment: i get only first record