# Operation count different id's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i need to do this operation:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Count the total of each number of records with a different 'rrpp': 1,2,3,4  ∞

I always use this to sum the records of a RRPP:

```
  $variable = Modelo::where('dia_id' , $request->id)->where('rrpp' , 1)->count('id');
```

but this way I only get the result of 1 in specific.
And what I need is to get the result like this

help, thanks

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group

Answer (score 0):

you only get result 1 because you use this `where('dia_id' , $request->id)` in your query,
if you want to count rrpp=1 use this query:

```
$variable = Modelo::where('rrpp' , 1)->count('id');
```

if you want to count all rrpp use this query:

```
$variable = Modelo::select('rrpp', 
    DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('rrpp')
    ->get()
```