# Count on GroupBy on Pivot data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship

I've got a `many-to-many` relationship between a `user` and a `match`, and I have a `availability` column on the pivot table which is an `enum`:

`'available'`, `'not-available'`, `'tbc'`

```
<?p
...
class User extends Model

public function matches() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Match::class)->withPivot('availability');
}
```

```
<?p
...
class Match extends Model

public function users() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('availability');
}
```

| match_id | user_id | availability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | available |
| 4 | 1 | tbc |
| 4 | 3 | available |
| 4 | 5 | tbc |
| 4 | 4 | not-available |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | 4 | not-available |

I'm trying to get the count of the availabilities for the players for a given match.

So that I can return something like:

```
[
  "availability" => "available",
  "count" => 17,
],
[
  "availability" => "not-available",
  "count" => 12,
],
[
  "availability" => "tbc",
  "count" => 4,
]
```

I feel like I should be able to use a `withCount` when I eager load the users on a model, but I can't workout how to do it on the pivot data.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of a way to query that from the `Match` model, for example. `Match::with(['users'])->find(4)` would include them all, with their pivot, and you could then do a [Collection `groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby), but it might just be simpler to do `DB::table('match_user')->select('availability', DB::raw('COUNT(user_id) AS count'))->groupBy('availability')->where('match_id', 4)->get()`. Do either of those work for your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group)

Comment: Thanks both. That's what I've implemented until now, but I was hoping to do it using the Eloquent builder rather than DB so that I could use it in as a method in my `MatchBuilder` class which extends the `Builder`.